# JQuery AJAX serialize getting null values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't find it out why this is not working.I have done this before a lot of times but this time this is not event working seriously don't know please help me find it out

**HTML(signup.html)**

```
<form role="form" id="signupForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first_name" class="control-label"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> First Name</label> <input
                type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="firstName"
                for="first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last_name" class="control-label"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Last Name</label> <input
                type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="lastName"
                for="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="control-label"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label> <input
                type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" id="username"
                for="user_name" placeholder="Enter Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Email</label> <input
                type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
                for="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mobile_number"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> Mobile Number</label> <input
                type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile_number"
                id="mobile_number" for="mobile_number"
                placeholder="Enter Mobile Number">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
                Password</label> <input type="password" class="form-control"
                name="password" id="password" for="password"
                placeholder="Enter Password">
            <!--<ul>
             <li class="help-block red"> *password must be 8 characters long</li>
             <li class="help-block red"> *password must contain an Uppercase letter </li>
             <li class="help-block red"> *password must contain an Lowercase letter </li>
             <li class="help-block red"> *password must contain a special character </li>
             <li class="help-block red"> *password must contain a number            </li>
            </ul>-->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirm_password"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Confirm Password</label> <input
                type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password"
                id="confirmPassword" for="confirm_password"
                placeholder="Enter Password again">
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown form-group">
            <label for="security_question"><span class="secQue"></span>
                Security Questions </label><br> <select name="security_question"
                id="secQue" class="btn btn-default">
                <option value=""> security Question? </option>
                <option value="what is your school name?"> what is your school name? </option>
                <option value="what is your native place  name?"> what is your native place  name? </option>
                <option value="what is your favourite place?"> what is your favourite place? </option>
                <option value="what is your favourite food?"> what is your favourite food? </option>
                <option value="what is your pet name?"> what is your pet name? </option>
            </select>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="answer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                Answer</label> <input type="answer" class="form-control" name="answer"
                id="answer" for="answer" placeholder="Enter Answer">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user_city"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> City</label> <input type="text"
                class="form-control" name="user_city" id="city" for="city"
                placeholder="Enter city">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="createAccount" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**JQuery(accounts.js)**

```
$(function(){

var bCreateAccount = $('#createAccount');

//Invokes createAccount function
bCreateAccount.on('click',createAccount);

//calls the SignupServlet AJAX request
function createAccount(){

    $("#signupForm").on('submit' , function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
                url : 'SignupServlet',
                type:'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data : $('#signupForm').serializeArray(),
                success : function(response){
                console.log('Response :' +response);    
                },
                error : function(){
                    console.log('Error :' +error);
                }
            });
        });     
}
```

});

**SignupServlet**

```
private void getParameters(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    firstName = request.getParameter("first_name");
    lastName = request.getParameter("last_name");
    userName = request.getParameter("user_name");
    email = request.getParameter("email");
    mobileNumber = request.getParameter("mobile_number");
    password = request.getParameter("password");
    confirmPassword = request.getParameter("confirm_password");
    securityQuestion = request.getParameter("security_question");
    answer = request.getParameter("answer");
    userCity = request.getParameter("user_city");
}
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Inside SignupServlet");
    getParameters(request, response);

    System.out.println("Username : "+userName);
```

}

I am not able to find out whats the problem with this code.Guyz please help me to get the solution.It will be really helpful.

Comment: Is your data sending properly to the server? (Check the network tab of the browser you're using (F12))

Comment: dumping your code and saying "its not working" is off topic. At least include some more specific error messages or problem you are encountering

Comment: Try adding type="submit" to your button.

Comment: @AndrewLohr I know this isn't a proper way but I just want to show the code to ensure I'm not missing something.

Comment: I don't know How it worked but the only thing I did is that I removed the form id and just used the form tag itself and it just worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your content type is for json but you're not posting the data as json nor is your server expecting json.

Remove the content type parameter from the ajax request so it will be application/x-www-form-urlencoded which is what your server side code seem to be expecting.

Comment: Thats not the problem it is something else I have checked it before but id didn't worked.